# How do you concatenate multiple range look-ups in a multi-conditioned COUNTIFS statement?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm building off of a COUNTIFS statement that I have counting certain things. I wanted to add another parameter to the COUNTIFS statement.

The current working COUNTIFS:

```
=COUNTIFS('Fleet Maintenance Penetration'!$O$16:$O$1072,">="&DATEVALUE("5/1/2017"),'Fleet Maintenance Penetration'!$O$16:$O$1072,"<="&DATEVALUE("5/31/2017"),'Fleet Maintenance Penetration'!$N$16:$N$1072,"C",'Fleet Maintenance Penetration'!$C$16:$C$1072,"Abu Dhabi/Amiri Flight")
```

Now I want to take that COUNTIFS and add one more parameter to it. I'm looking for certain values in a range on the workbook. The Range is also referencing the worksheet "Fleet Maintenance Penetration" just like all the other refernces in the formula.

The Range I want to look for a value of let's say "P" is R16:BH1072. I realized that I'm not able to write out the code like this:

```
=COUNTIFS('Fleet Maintenance Penetration'!$O$16:$O$1072,">="&DATEVALUE("5/1/2017"),'Fleet Maintenance Penetration'!$O$16:$O$1072,"<="&DATEVALUE("5/31/2017"),'Fleet Maintenance Penetration'!$N$16:$N$1072,"C",'Fleet Maintenance Penetration'!$C$16:$C$1072,"Air India",'Fleet Maintenance Penetration'!$R$16:$BH$1072,"P")
```

So I was able to successfully add one parameter by adding the range of only 1 column "R".

```
=COUNTIFS('Fleet Maintenance Penetration'!$O$16:$O$1072,">="&DATEVALUE("5/1/2017"),'Fleet Maintenance Penetration'!$O$16:$O$1072,"<="&DATEVALUE("5/31/2017"),'Fleet Maintenance Penetration'!$N$16:$N$1072,"C",'Fleet Maintenance Penetration'!$C$16:$C$1072,"Air India",'Fleet Maintenance Penetration'!$R$16:$R$1072,"P")
```

How would I add or concatenate the additional Columns S-BH in this formula???

Comment: Let's say that "P" occurs 3 times in a single row, such as R16:BH16, does it count as 1 occurrence?  Or does it count as 3 occurrences?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`COUNTIFS` is great, but unfortunately has very restricting rules and syntax. As soon as the criteria gets more complicated, it can't be made to work. On the other hand `SUMPRODUCT` with arrays is a more flexible solution for more complex criteria.

You may try this formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(
('Fleet Maintenance Penetration'!$O$16:$O$1072 >=Date(2017,5,1))*
('Fleet Maintenance Penetration'!$O$16:$O$1072<=Date(2017,5,31))*
('Fleet Maintenance Penetration'!$N$16:$N$1072="C")*
('Fleet Maintenance Penetration'!$C$16:$C$1072="Air India")*
('Fleet Maintenance Penetration'!$R$16:$BH$1072="P"))
```

p.s. the additional condition will try to match any `"P"` in the same row columns `R:BH`. If many `"P"` on the same row are present, the row will be counted as many times.

Comment: Actually, I think it will count it multiple times.

Comment: Hey guys thanks for your responses. I did try the SUMPRODUCT formula and had to go in that range and delete some errors that were pre-existing in the worksheet. The formula I have now has a #VALUE! in the cell now.

Comment: =SUMPRODUCT('Fleet Maintenance Penetration'!$O$16:$O$1072>=DATEVALUE("5/1/2017"))*('Fleet Maintenance Penetration'!$O$16:$O$1072<=DATEVALUE("5/31/2017"))*('Fleet Maintenance Penetration'!$N$16:$N$1072="C")*('Fleet Maintenance Penetration'!$C$16:$C$1072="Air India")*('Fleet Maintenance Penetration'!R16:BH1072="P")

Comment: @Motorhead1308 the `#value` is most likely due to the date formats entered in the formula (failure of `DATEVALUE`). What is the date formal in your setting? is it m/d/y or d/m/y?

Comment: I used error checking to ensure there weren't anymore errors present in the specified range of !R16:BH1072="P"

Comment: Would you try substituting `DATEVALUE("5/1/2017")` with `Date(2017,5,1)` and `DATEVALUE("5/31/2017")` with `Date(2017,5,31)`> that is better anyway because it is locale independent.

Comment: =SUMPRODUCT('Fleet Maintenance Penetration'!$O$16:$O$1072>=DATE(2017,5,1))*('Fleet Maintenance Penetration'!$O$16:$O$1072<=DATE(2017,5,31))*('Fleet Maintenance Penetration'!$N$16:$N$1072="C")*('Fleet Maintenance Penetration'!$C$16:$C$1072="Abu Dhabi/Amiri Flight")*('Fleet Maintenance Penetration'!R16:BH1072="P")                                                                  
                                                                                                           
                  This did not work either ..................... Still a #VALUE!

Comment: You mistyped it. There should be two `(` after sumproduct and one more `)` at the end :/. Please try it with copy/paste from here.

Comment: @A.S.H. that did return a value!!! Now I will test further to ensure that the values are correct on multiple instances.........When confirmed I will upvote your answer!!!

Comment: I do believe after doing a few of them that this is working properly! I can't thank you enough!